Cycles Animation Render Flickering (Motion Blur Artifacts)
I need some help with removing flickering in the final animation render in Cycles when motion blur is enabled.
https://youtu.be/47KbA0EvxOA
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Increasing render Max Samples from 128 to 256
Changing Motion Blur > Position to different settings
Adjusting Motion Blur > Shutter to various values

Any suggestions on what else I could try?
